# How to pass request user to serializer in UpdateApiView with partial_update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have view like below. I have edited_user in my model . I want to pass current_user to serializer and in serializer I will override update() function. Problem is I cant find way to pass current user. Can Anyone help ?

```
class Update(UpdateAPIView):  
    serializer_class = serializer_class
    queryset = model.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.field == 1:
            return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution like below. It works fine.

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial, context={"user": request.user})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()

def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer method of choice (I'm using `validate()` as an example), you can get the user like this:

```py
def validate(self, data):
    # get user and check sanity
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
        # do what you like with the user
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    else:
        raise ValidationError("user not found in request")
```